# Find path to cURL?

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, curl, debian-jessie

My `phpinfo();` shows cURL is installed on the server but when I use the command `/usr/bin/curl` it returns `/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/curl: not found`.

Now when I type `which curl`, it doesn't return anything.

Any ideas how to properly find path to cURL?

Comment: Did you try `whereis curl`?

Comment: @SpiderPig typing `whereis curl` returns: `curl:` It doesn't seem to look like a path?

Comment: Note that there are `curl` and `libcurl` packages. Perhaps libcurl is installed but curl itself is not. What does `apt list --installed | grep curl` show?

Comment: Hmmm... it says this things are installed: `libcurl3/oldstable` `php-curl/jessie` `php5-curl/oldstable` `php7.0-curl/jessie`

Comment: @glennjackman I went ahead and installed `curl` it does seem I've mistaken `libcurl` for `curl`. You can create an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: As [this answer states](https://superuser.com/a/1477392/167207), the Curl library that PHP uses—and is reflected in `phpinfo()`—ha utterly nothing to do with the command line version of Curl.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was self-solved a year or so ago as indicated in the comments: The user had to simply install the command line `curl` to get things working. They mistook the Curl library that PHP uses from command line Curl.

Answer (score 6):

The `/usr/bin/curl` commandline executable is not the same as the php-curl library.

Both *link* to `libcurl.so`, the DLL/shared library which provides the functionality under the hood.

But you would need to install the curl package to get the CLI binary.